# Creating an empty file in Ruby: "touch" equivalent?

Tags: ruby, file

What is the best way to create an **empty** file in Ruby?

Something similar to the Unix command, [touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_%28Unix%29):

```
touch file.txt
```

Comment: You can always do `\`touch file.txt\``

Comment: @Mark: even on windows?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

[`FileUtils.touch`](http://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/touch/class) looks like what it does, and mirrors<sup>*</sup> the `touch` command:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.touch('file.txt')
```

<sup>* Unlike [touch(1)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/touch/) you can't update mtime or atime alone. It's also missing a few other nice options.</sup>

Answer (score 51):

If you are worried about file handles:

```
File.open("foo.txt", "w") {}
```

From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-open):

> If the optional code block is given, it will be passed the opened file
>   as an argument, and the File object will automatically be closed when
>   the block terminates.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sending the new file to another process, so the handle needs to be closed immediately.

Comment: Worth pointing out that this doesn't actually mirror `touch` - it will overwrite the file if it exists.

Comment: Use the append mode and the file will not be truncated if it already exists

 File.open( "foo.txt", "a") {}

This also does not mirror 'touch', but then 'touch(1)' was not the question.

Comment: Using "a" doesn't update the mtime.  ("touch" was the subtitle, so Google brings us people who want a Ruby touch.)

Comment: on *nix systems, Who is the file owner when it is created this way?

Answer (score 29):

In Ruby 1.9.3+, you can use `File.write` (a.k.a [`IO.write`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-write)):

```
File.write("foo.txt", "")
```

For earlier version, either [`require "backports/1.9.3/file/write"`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) or use `File.open("foo.txt", "w") {}`

Comment: That's much cleaner, but unfortunately I need to be backwards compatible. I'll keep it in mind for future use though.

Comment: Overwrites it if already exists, I presume?  Good to see you again BTW :)

Comment: @rogerdpack yes, it overwrites if it exists.

Answer (score 4):

And also, less advantageous, but very brief:

```
`touch file.txt`
```

Comment: Will fork separate pricess, so is very slow.

Comment: And is already mentioned in the comments, which I haven't noticed earlier.

Answer (score -2):

Just an example:

```
File.open "foo.txt", "w"
```

Comment: Does this leave an open file handle behind, like it would in some other languages?

Comment: @Abhi: It does, but garbage collection will handle it at some point. To avoid that, though, pass an empty block (See Michael Kohl's answer)

Comment: When is "at some point" going to happen? At the end of the script, or immediately because it hasn't been assigned to any variable? I'm creating the file so other processes on the system can start working with it immediately, and they will be blocked if the file handle is still open for writing.

Comment: File.open("foo.txt", "w").close() solves the filehandle issue, but FileUtils.touch is a better solution.

Comment: Don't leave open files handles like that :-)