# Not able to create a file for writing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

I am uploading `txt` files using `carrierwave`. The files are not small (80 MB - 500 MB) and I want to remove some of the lines to reduce this size (about 80% of the file size is going to be reduced).

I have created a model method in order to clear these lines:

```
require 'fileutils'

def clear_unnecessary_lines
  old_file_path = Rails.root.join('public').to_s + log_file.to_s
  new_file_path = old_file_path.sub! '.txt', '_temp.txt'
  File.open(old_file_path, 'r') do |old_file|
    File.open(new_file_path, 'w') do |new_file|
      old_file.each_line do |line|
        new_file.write(line) unless line.grep(/test/).size > 0
      end
    end
  end
  FileUtils.mv new_file_path, old_file_path
end
```

but I am getting error when I am trying to `open` the new file saying there is no such file. As I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911669/create-file-in-ruby) opening a file with the `w` option should create an empty file for writing. Then why I am getting such error?

Also, since `log_file` column is holding the path to the original file, and I am changing it, could you tell how to rename the new file with the old name? As I have checked I should specify only `old` and `new` names, not paths.

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /home/gotqn/Rails/LogFilesAnalyser/LogFilesAnalyser/public/uploads/log_file/log_file/3/log_debug_temp.txt
```

---

It is strange that If I execute the following command in rails console, it is not throwing an error and the file is created.

```
File.open('/home/gotqn/Rails/LogFilesAnalyser/LogFilesAnalyser/public/uploads/log_file/log_file/3/log_debug_temp.txt','w')
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's the line you think it is that's causing the problem?  Is it actually erroring on `File.open(old_file_path, 'r')`?  File.open with the "w" option doesn't need the file to exist already but with the "r" option the file does need to exist (since it's reading it).

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes, I am sure. I have commented the code about `new_file` and it is working. Also, note the error is about `log_debug_temp.txt`, where the name of the `old_file` is `log_debug.txt`

Comment: Is the script running with necessary permissions?

Comment: @BroiSatse I cannot tell. The method is called in the controller like this `@log_file.clear_unnecessary_lines` in the `create` action. Since, `carierwave` is creating files in this directory, I guess I can create files, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, i see your problem now.  When you do this

```
new_file_path = old_file_path.sub! '.txt', '_temp.txt'
```

you call the "self-altering" version of `sub`, ie `sub!`.  This will actually change the value of `old_file_path` as a side effect.  Then, in the next line, you try to open this file, which hasn't been created yet.  Take out the exclamation mark and you should be fine.

Comment: So it was erroring on the `File.open(old_file_path, 'r')` line after all then? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, as a matter of fact it was.