# I can't create a file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm pretty new to Ruby. I want to create a file by writing:

```
file.new "test.txt", "w"
```

And de result is:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'file' for main:Object
from (irb):4
from c:/Ruby21/bin/irb:11:in '<main>'
```

I don't know what it means. And another question if I may: How do I say in what folder I want to save the file?

Comment: `File` not `file`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911669/create-file-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing `file` with a lower case `f`, which means you are accessing a local variable or a method. In order to access the [`File`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html) class, you must write it with a upper case `F`:

```
File.new 'test.txt', 'w' do |file|
  file.write 'Some text.'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be [`File`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html), not `file`.

```
File.new "test.txt", "w"
```

Answer (score 0):

`file` isn't defined, you have to use `File`:

```
File.new "test.txt", "w"
```