# writing encoded content to .ps1 file

Tags: ruby, powershell

I am trying to create a file .ps1 and writing  the content using ruby.But i'm getting error.Below is the code

```
output = File.open( "test.ps1", "w" )
  output << "$a = type c://edmundsapi-final ;(Get-Content C:\inetpub\sites\tsd_atlasapi\AppSettings.config) -replace '(?<=<add key="Edmunds" value=")[^"]*', $a | Set-Content C:\inetpub\sites\tsd_atlasapi\AppSettings.config "
 output.close
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: See "[mcve]" and Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is either:

```
File.open("test.ps1", w) {|f| f.write("$a = type c://edmundsapi-final ;(Get-Content C:\inetpub\sites\tsd_atlasapi\AppSettings.config) -replace '(?<=<add key="Edmunds" value=")[^"]*', $a | Set-Content C:\inetpub\sites\tsd_atlasapi\AppSettings.config ") }
```

or

```
out_file = File.new("test.ps1", "w") 
out_file.puts("$a = type c://edmundsapi-final ;(Get-Content C:\inetpub\sites\tsd_atlasapi\AppSettings.config) -replace '(?<=<add key="Edmunds" value=")[^"]*', $a | Set-Content C:\inetpub\sites\tsd_atlasapi\AppSettings.config ")

out_file.close
```

See "[How to create a file in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911669/create-file-in-ruby)" for a possible duplicate.

Comment: I tried it but giving me error: SyntaxError

c:/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/tsd_atlasapi/recipes/default.rb:435: syntax
error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')'
...ce '(?<=<add key="EdmundsApi" value=")[^"]*', $a | Set-Co...
      ^
c:/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/tsd_atlasapi/recipes/default.rb:435: syntax
error, unexpected ')', expecting '}'
...dd key="EdmundsApi" value=")[^"]*', $a | Set-Content C:\i...
                            ^

Comment: You need to check your quotes