# Ruby Sinatra - How to capture post json data and save to file

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How do I capture a Json data from POST route and save it to file? I have simple ruby sinatra code as below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

post '/' do
  values = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)
# How do I save "values" of JSON to file..
end
```

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2777863/390819) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

post '/' do
  values = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)
  File.open('file.txt', 'w') { |file| file.write(values) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for posting.. but somehow it is not working for me. I don't even see the file "file.txt" in the current directory, and even if I create a file.txt, after posting, the file.txt is empty. I wonder if  there something I missed.

Answer (score 1):

To write file in ruby you can use:

```
File.open('/your/path/file', 'w') { |file| file.write(values) }
```