# Ruby, Write User Input to a File

Tags: ruby, input

I have the following code, which hangs up on writing user input to a file.  What is my error here?

```
file=File.open("Debsfile.txt", "r+") do |file|
  file.puts "This is Deb's file. It's a great file. It has many characters, words and lines."
  file.puts "This is another line of text in Deb's file."
end
  puts "What is your favorite color?"
  color = gets
  color = color.chomp
  color.write
file.close

File.open("Debsfile.txt").readlines.each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If I run the program as yours, the error message is:

```
undefined method `write' for "red":String (NoMethodError)
```

The problem is you are calling `write` method on `color` which is a string object. You actually wanted to write the input color to the file, so, you need to call `write` method on a `File` (or `IO` object): `file.write color` like following:

```
File.open("Debsfile.txt", "r+") do |file|
  file.puts "This is Deb's file. It's a great file. It has many characters, words and lines."
  file.puts "This is another line of text in Deb's file."
  puts "What is your favorite color?"
  color = gets
  color = color.chomp  
  file.write color  # writing the color to the file here
end

File.open("Debsfile.txt").readlines.each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777802/how-to-write-to-file-in-ruby) for the details on how to write to file in Ruby.

Comment: Thank you I'll run that again as soon as possible.

Comment: This method can be shortened a bit by calling chomp directly on gets: color = gets.chomp

Answer (score 0):

```
file=File.open("Debsfile.txt", "a+") do |file|
```

## adds two lines of text to the file

```
file.puts "This is Deb's file. It's a great file. It has many characters, words and lines."
file.puts "This is another line of text in Deb's file."
#asks user for favorite color in console
puts "What is your favorite color?"
#assigns color to variable "color"
color = gets
#color.chomp cuts of the new line character so that you just have the user input
color = color.chomp
#adds the color to the end of the file
file.puts("Your favorite color is #{color}.") #writing the color to the file
```

end #end of file open

File.open("Debsfile.txt").readlines.each do |line|
  puts line
end

Comment: This is my code and I got it running correctly.  Thank you, K M, for the help.

Comment: Nice work! to shorten a bit, call chomp directly on gets: color = gets.chomp