# Generate category page in jekyll targeting github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to generate category pages for my github pages blog using jekyll.   When i run locally using `jekyll serve` this works because it can use my plugin.

Using this example [from the docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators) doesn't work because github will not generate custom plugins:

```
module Jekyll
  class CategoryPage < Page
    def initialize(site, base, dir, category)
      @site = site
      @base = base
      @dir = dir
      @name = 'index.html'

      self.process(@name)
      self.read_yaml(File.join(base, '_layouts'), 'category_index.html')
      self.data['category'] = category

      category_title_prefix = site.config['category_title_prefix'] || 'Category: '
      self.data['title'] = "#{category_title_prefix}#{category}"
    end
  end

  class CategoryPageGenerator < Generator
    safe true

    def generate(site)
      if site.layouts.key? 'category_index'
        dir = site.config['category_dir'] || 'categories'
        site.categories.each_key do |category|
          site.pages << CategoryPage.new(site, site.source, File.join(dir, category), category)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, it would work if I could generate my own pages that are not in the `_site` directory.  I would then check these in as "regular" pages even though they are generated by the system.

Is there any way to generate category pages outside of the `_site` directory  with jekyll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A)** You can write custom scripts (shell or Ruby or whatever) to **generate files anywhere using [file I/O operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777802/how-to-write-to-file-in-ruby).** In your above example, instead of adding new pages to the site, you can write out files with front-matter into your project directory. For example (Ruby):

```
open('somepath/#{category}/index.html', 'w') { |f|
  f << "---\n"
  f << "key: #{variable}\n"
  f << "---\n"
}
```

And of course, you have to **run it locally, before pushing** the project to GitHub.

---

**B)** Or you can **render your Jekyll site locally** and push only the `_site` contents to GitHub. You can then use **any plugin** you need. You have to create a `.nojekyll` file in the project root to [bypass Jekyll processing](https://blog.github.com/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/) on GitHub, and you have to add it to Jekyll's includes as well (in `_config.yml`):

`include:
  - .nojekyll`

Then you can render the site (`jekyll build`) and **push contents of `_site` directory** to GitHub. You can automate this step with a little shell script.